# How to make a new dictionary from the values of (same lengths and same keys) two different dictionaries, using as key-value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

Two dictionaries with the same keys and same length,

```
dict_val = {0: [0.2, 0.8], 1: [0.3125, 0.6875]}
dict_word = {0:['bank#0', 'rock#0'], 1:['bank#1', 'rock#1'] }
```

How to create a new dictionary using the values of the above two dictionaries as "word_val" below,

```
word_val = {bank#0 : 0.2, rock#0: 0.8, bank#1: 0.3125, rock#1: 0.687}
```

note: values of one dictionary is using as keys and values of the other dictionary as values in the newly created dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip` and a nested dict comprehension:

```
{k_: v_ for k in dict_val for k_, v_ in zip(dict_word[k], dict_val[k])}
# {'bank#0': 0.2, 'rock#0': 0.8, 'bank#1': 0.3125, 'rock#1': 0.6875}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) with `zip`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> dict(zip(chain(*dict_word.values()), chain(*dict_val.values())))
{'bank#0': 0.2, 'rock#0': 0.8, 'bank#1': 0.3125, 'rock#1': 0.6875}
```

Python 3.6+ onwards, dicts are guaranteed to maintain insertion order, so if you are using 3.6+, this solution is safe.

Comment: Here it is assumed that dictionaries are going to be ordered. In Python 3.4+, dictionary maintain the insertion order, and this solution will work. However, in older version it'll give unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Anonymous True, I will update that in the post.